# SUSE OS 15 Service Pack 3 - How to update the name of network adapter from ens33 to eth0 with DHCP configuration

Tags: network-interface, suse, sles

The ifconfig output shows network adapter as ens33 currently.

I want to configure the system to DHCP with network adapter name as eth0.

Please help.

**[UPDATED]**
I am able to update the network name by using the below steps:

1. vi /etc/default/grub
2. Update GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0
3. If empty place this variable with this value GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0"
4. grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/sles/grub.cfg

Currently I need to update the configuration from static to dhcp.

Comment: Does this help: https://www.xmodulo.com/change-network-interface-names-permanently-linux.html

Comment: It does talk about the renaming of the network adapter. How can I configure it to dhcp is the second problem. I have updated the question name ( sorry my bad it was not clear on the question title)

Comment: What network services are you running?